# What book do you recommend for new Tex users?

Tags: books, tutorials, learning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex)

I'm new to Tex.  Just downloaded the program for Mac.  I'm using TeXShop and I wanted to see if anyone could recommend a good book as a beginner's reference guide?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Please see the related question: [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex)

Comment: I think this is a good book "latex - A Document Preparation System - Leslie Lamport Also here is a good read http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Introduction